# What Ebean Version am I using? (Play Framework)

Tags: playframework, ebean

I've added javaEbean as a libraryDependency in my build.sbt (play 2.3.7).

How do I figure out what EBean https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/releases release this corresponds to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ebean 3.3.4. In Play 2.4.x there is a much more recent version, so you may want to use it instead, if you need the newer version and can afford the update.

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/project/Dependencies.scala#L31

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayImport.scala#L30